# wireless detected but Can't connect to network, Wifi card intel pro wireless N100 BGN

Tags: intel, intel-wireless, internet-connection

Thanks in advance, I installed Linux Mint kernel 3.0.0-12 x64 ,wireless is detected and  I configure it in network manager but can't coonect, there are the results of command line:

```
$ iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C network**
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:1e:64:51:c9:d6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:d7400000-d7401fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 48:5b:39:99:8f:16
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:51 memory:d3800000-d383ffff ioport:8000(size=128
```

---

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thank you.

Comment: they're probably going to flag this as off topic since you're asking about mint

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is "tx-power off", you can try to type this:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 14
```

14dbm is the maximum tx-power for my card, I don't know your.

However, I think the card is powered off,  have you turned on the wireless? :-)